# Rails friendly Url how to prevent duplicates? and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-url

I am using friendly url.

I am using that problem when I visit http://localhost:3000/9 it shows the same page as http://localhost:3000/vind-rejse

My Category vind-rejse have the ID of 9

How do I get rails only to respond on http://localhost:3000/vind-rejse?

And how do I link to konkurrancers show action?

My Kategoris controller:

```
 def show
    @kategori = Kategori.find(params[:id])
    @konkurrancer = @kategori.konkurrancers.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @kategori }
    end
  end
```

My Konkurrancers controller:

```
  def show
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer }
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
match ':kategoris/:id' => 'konkurrancers#show'
match '/:id' => 'kategoris#show'
```

Comment: are you using `def to_param #... end`?

Comment: Yes protected
  def assign_cached_slug
 self.cached_slug = self.name.gsub(/\s+/, '_').gsub(/[^\w\-]/, '')
  end

  def to_param
    self.name
  end

Comment: could you post your controller code (the show action)?

Comment: I have now posted the two controllers show action

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
@kategori = Kategori.find_by_name!(params[:id])
```

and for your routes

```
match ':kategoris/:id' => 'konkurrancers#show', :as => 'whatever'
```

and in your views

```
<%= link_to "Whatever", whatever_path(9) %>
```

Comment: I'd just suggest using `find_by_name!` vs `find_by_name` so that it raises and error instead of returning `nil` if no record is found.